# Two effects with only one javascript class

Tags: javascript, class, graph

I want to create a javascript class of my own. My question is, how do i create a function with two differents effects depending on the context.

Here is an example :

```
function Matrix(str) {
this.G = 2 dim array;
this.e = function(x,y){
    G[x][y] = 3 // if the user types myGraph.e(1,1) = 3;
    return G[x][y] // if user call myGraph.e(1,1);
}
```

So how can I have two different results with only one function ? `myGraph.e(1,1) = 3` and `myGraph.e(1,1)`

Thx !

Comment: the syntax overloading you've requested is impossible in Javascript

Comment: `myGraph.e(1,1) = 3` is not valid JavaScript code.

Comment: You are using global variable `G`, not the instance's variable. In javascript, writing `this.` is not optional like it is in java.

Comment: @Esailija that's hardly the worst problem with what the OP's trying to do, though ;-)

Comment: @Alnitak So I can only do someting like `myGraph.e(1,1,3)`

Comment: @PaulFournel yes, exactly.  You'd be better with explicit `get` and `set` functions IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly modifying @Esalija's answer:

```
this.e = function(x, y, value) {
    if (typeof value !== 'undefined') {
        this.G[x][y] = value;
    }
    return this.G[x][y];  // always return the value
}
```

NB: it's more common for the *first* dimension of a 2-D array to represent `y`, not `x`.

Answer (score 1):

That cannot be done, but you can simply take third argument:

```
this.e = function( x , y, value){
    switch( arguments.length ) {
         case 3: this.G[x][y] = value; return; // myGraph.e( 1, 1, 3 );
         case 2: return this.G[x][y]; // myGraph.e( 1, 1 );
         default: throw new TypeError( "..." );
    }
}
```